# Enter the URL from Scrypted Google Device Access Settings page (bottom box - 'Pub/Sub Address') in the 'Endpoint URL'

Tags: homebridge

I am struggling with scrypted getting google device access set up.
I am at this stage and not too sure if I am looking for the wrong thing/what I am looking for and where.
Can anyone assist in where to find the Pub/Sub address? I wasnt able to find it.

Thanks

I have (i think) successfully got to the end stage and have not gone further because I couldnt find this.